# Example of a chain without a supremum in a non Archimedean ordered field

Tags: field-theory, supremum-and-infimum, ordered-fields

I give [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-non-archimedean-ordered-field/) the example of a non-Archimedean ordered field. I know that the field is not order complete.

What is a simple example in that field of a chain without a supremum?

Comment: In any non-Archimedean ordered field the set $\Bbb{N}=\{ 1, 1+1 , 1+1+1 , \dots \}$ is bounded above but it has no supremum.

Comment: I suggest not to use the same symbol $P$ in your article for the polynomial $P(x)$ and the positive cone $P$: I found it quite confusing.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks good remark!

Comment: Rather than linking to the external website, please summarize the content here, so that loading the external website is not necessary to understand the question. That improves the question by adding context, it removes a dependency of the question on another site, and it reduces any appearance that the question might be advertising for the site (especially given your username).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the very thing that shows it's not Archimedean that witnesses that.

More specifically, $\Bbb N$, is such chain. If $x$ is the supremum of all the natural numbers, then $x-1$ should be smaller than a natural number $k$ and therefore $x=(x-1)+1$ should be at most $k+1$ which is a contradiction.